# Vue Cli 3 build custom directory for different type of files

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, vue-cli-3

I am new in using vue to build web app.
By default, use `npm run build`, it will build the following structure:

[image]

But I hope to build as follow:

[image]

Then, how can I write the `vue.config.js` as output like what I want?

Comment: Where are the images in your sources? If they're in your `public` directory, just create a `register` directory in there for them. As for your CSS and JS files, why is it important?

Comment: This is built in `dist` folder.  It is because of the server structure, it should be output like that.

Comment: Yes, I know that is your `dist` folder but I asked you **where are the images in your sources?**

Comment: Also, _"It is because of the server structure"_ doesn't make much sense. Can you elaborate?

Comment: 'css' change to 'css/register', 'img' change to 'images/register' and 'js' change to 'js/register'. It is because of we are using old apache server with php framework.

Comment: That still doesn't make much sense and you haven't actually answered any of my questions

Comment: Oh I know, the images are in `src/assets`

Comment: css and js files are no external, becasue all of them in .vue components

Comment: Someone is asking a [similar question here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1967) and just as I am doing, people are asking _"**why?**"_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [this GitHub issue as an example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1967), you should be able to achieve this by adding something like this to your configuration...

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module.rule('images').use('url-loader')
      .loader('file-loader') // replaces the url-loader
      .tap(options => Object.assign(options, {
        name: 'images/register/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
      }))
    config.module.rule('svg').use('file-loader')
      .tap(options => Object.assign(options, {
        name: 'images/register/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
      }))
  },
  css: {
    extract: {
      filename: 'css/register/[name].[hash:8].css',
      chunkFilename: 'css/register/[name].[hash:8].css'
    }
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: 'js/register/[name].[hash:8].js',
      chunkFilename: 'js/register/[name].[hash:8].js'
    }
  }
}
```

See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js for more information and examples.