# Vuejs production build - how to change generated "img" folder name into "images"

Tags: vue.js

In my vue-cli3 project I get the usual index.html + 3 folders (css, js, img) when I run a build command.

Is it possible to change the name of the img folder into "images" somehow ?

I imagine I have to add something to my vue.config.js to instruct webpack, but I can't find any info on this.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: You have similar topic here: [Vue Cli 3 build custom directory for different type of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196456/vue-cli-3-build-custom-directory-for-different-type-of-files)

Answer (score 5):

as per @Emin Mešić I was able to achive this by adding this to my vue.config.js

```
chainWebpack: config => {
  config.module.rule('images').use('url-loader')
    .loader('file-loader') // replaces the url-loader
    .tap(options => Object.assign(options, {
      name: 'images/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    }))
  config.module.rule('svg').use('file-loader')
    .tap(options => Object.assign(options, {
      name: 'images/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    }))
  },
```